Mechanisms underlying plasticity of inhibitory synapses
In introductory textbooks to neuroscience, the mechanism presented for synaptic plasticity is Hebbian learning (see Hebbian theory, Wikipedia) which can be summed up in "Neurons that fire together, wire together.".
Experiments seem to back this principle through the mechanism of spike-timing-dependent plasticity. The main observation being that if neuron B often fires just after neuron A, an excitatory synapse from A to B will be reinforced (and, interestingly, it seems that when B fires just before neuron A, this will have the opposite effect of lowering the strength of the connection).
My understanding is that this mechanism is documented for excitatory synapses, not inhibitory.
What are the mechanisms underlying inhibitory synapses plasticity?

Are you thinking about a brain area where inhibition is separate from the principal cells (e.g., neocortex, hippocampus) or where inhibitory cells produce projections to other places (e.g., targets of the cerebellum)?

@BryanKrause I don't know much about this distinction yet, but an answer could address both cases I suppose.
